# Too much emails from fail2ban

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

I set up fail2ban on my Ubuntu server and specified an email address for notifications. I only want to be informed when a host is banned, but currently I get way to much emails with messages like

> Hi, The jail apache-auth has been started successfully /stopped. Regards,
>   Fail2Ban

How can I suppress this kind of notifications?

Answer (score 2):

Comment out the actions in `/etc/fail2ban/actions.d/mail.conf` and replace them with an empty action:

```
#actionstart = printf %%b "Hi,\n
#              The jail <name> has been started successfully.\n
#              Regards,\n
#              Fail2Ban"|mail -s "[Fail2Ban] <name>: started  on `uname -n`" <dest>
actionstart = 
#actionstop = printf %%b "Hi,\n [...]
actionstop =
```

Comment: Thx, do you know what is meant by "starting/stoping" a jail? I get the more than once for each jail

Comment: From a quick glance at my fail2ban logs (running on debian) it seems that a jail is started when the fail2ban service is started. I only get this message once per jail in the logs. I don't have email notifications enabled, I would get hundreds of messages per day.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work

Comment: @user2224350 Please see my edit.